# Using PHP and Javascript to Reload Data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading Content using Ajax with PHP Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118023/loading-content-using-ajax-with-php-include)

So, I have a bit of a problem. I have a page, and in the page is a div, and in the div is an include for php. It includes a page that actually populates the div with content. Now, my issue is I want to make it so the div will refresh with more content loaded up from a MySQL server. My problem is going from the anchor link in the page, and using a (what, probably ajax I think?) call to a php function to load more content from the database. Thanks to any help anyone can give!

Comment: You could do ajax request to your php function then when there is response, you append the response on your element where you want to add it

Comment: Your description and title do not match at all. Have a look at jquery load

Comment: Sorry about the mismatched title. I guess I should rephrase...I'm trying to implement paging results from a database in php...when I press the next button, I want javascript to return my session variable + 1 to php

Answer (score 0):

render a javascript snippet which will do a ajax post on click of that anchor. in that php, replace the div's innerHTML with the content you loaded from Mysql.

```
                `jQuery(div_id).html(content)`
```

will replace the div's html with content.